# sql str replace problems

Tags: sql, sybase, str-replace

I have been trying to replace a list of about 100 entries of a url in a database and haven't had much luck. This is what I need to do:

Grab current URL: /one/two/three/four/differenteverytime.pdf
and update it in it's current entry to: /two/three/four/differenteverytime.pdf

Every URL starts with that pattern so I am looking to mass update.

I have tried a number of commands with REPLACE and str_REPLACE, but to no avail. Any help is much appreciated, I wasn't able to find a straightforward answer in older entries.

Comment: Do you mean every url starts with URL:/one/ or every url starts with *:/*/ ? ie can you replace 'URL:/one/ with nothing or do you need to remove *:/*/ where * could be 1 to n chars?

Comment: Yes I would like to replace it with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX) = '/one/two/three/four/differenteverytime.pdf'


SELECT STUFF(@str, 1, LEN(LEFT(@str, CHARINDEX('/', @str, 2)))-1 , '')
```

using this as part of an `UPDATE` you would do

```
UPDATE tbl
SET col = STUFF(col, 1, LEN(LEFT(col, CHARINDEX('/', col, 2)))-1 , '')
```

Comment: select str_REPLACE ( t.url, '/one/two', '/two' ) FROM dbo.table t

Allows me to grab all the strings formatted the way I want them. But updating them in place is the part where I am having trouble.

Comment: do you mean you are having problems using it in an `UPDATE` query like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45a72/1)?

Comment: @user1672092 p.s. I would be careful using `REPLACE` type functions and make sure it only replaces the first occurrence because you could end up messing with the `'/differenteverytime.pdf'` part also

Comment: Yes I am having problems using them as part of an UPDATE. That is my concern. If there weren't hundreds of entries that required this, I would just do them one by one.

Comment: so you just have to do it like in the fiddle it'll update all the records [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90f2f/1)

Comment: UPDATE dbo.table SET url = str_REPLACE(url, '/one/two', '/two' )

Autocommit needed to be turned on to accomplish this for many rows as well. Thanks everyone for the help.